# How to send a message from website to moodle?

Tags: javascript, moodle

I'm developing a website and I have to type a text in a box and send it as a message to moodle with some button. I have already made it with sending messages to linkedin, twitter and email but I don't know how to send to moodle and I'd be grateful if you help me.

Comment: Can you please explain what you expect. I'm not familar with moodle (and maybe many other who may help aren't too). And I guess there are at least 2 ways of doing what you want and with a 50% chance both solutions are not what you expect. Please show us an example or just some sketches (storyboard whatever). Further, tell us, which technologies you can't (or won't) use (for example: you tagged this question as [javascript], I would assume you do not want to use server-side technologies).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use web services

Follow the instructions to set up Moodle as a web service

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Using_web_services

Then have a look through the list of functions available for web services - in your moodle site go to site admin -> plugins -> web services -> api documentation

or go direct to the url yourwebsite.com/admin/webservice/documentation.php

In the documentation there is a function to send instant messages to users :

core_message_send_instant_messages()

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up social media so that they work within Moodle. Perhaps the easiest approach is to use a theme (in Moodle 2.6). I would recommend Essential. It has a form that lets you enter in social media. It is a responsive theme.

http://www.packtpub.com/designing-moodle-themes/video